# How to display TextView Right to left ever if starts with Left to right char (English , numbers and more..)?

Tags: android, unicode, textview, right-to-left

How to display TextView Right to left ever if starts with Left to right char (English , numbers and more..)?

I can use

```
android:textDirection="rtl"
```

but i want to support older version than 17 .

My other solution is to check :

```
public static boolean isStartWithEnglishUnicodeOrDigits(String str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    String abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String digits = "1234567890";
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < abc.length(); i++) {
            if (str.charAt(0) == abc.charAt(i)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < digits.length(); i++) {
            if (str.charAt(0) == digits.charAt(i)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

if true i add char to indicates thats force right to left like that :

```
    x = "\u200F" + x;
```

I hate this solution so i"m asking you how would tackle this issue ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

just set your TextView width to your wanted size

and set :

> android:gravity="right"

Comment: my size or gravity is not the problem , the text direction is

Comment: do you mean that you have several TextViews?

Answer (score 0):

> but i want to support older version than 17

but Android only supports natively rtl text starting from 17: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

The only way is to do your own hack, of find some library that does the hack, but there won't be any Android native support.

Comment: I don't need a library for my problem , as i wrote i have alternative method i tried to avoid but it looks like my solution is the best for now .